# Django rest knox set ttl on basis of platform

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am using [django-rest-knox](https://github.com/James1345/django-rest-knox) for drf authentication. I have succesffuly implemented it but now I want to set token expiry based on the requesting platform. If a user is logged in from mobile I want to have different TTL as of logged in through web. How could I accomplish this. I am using header value to differentiate between platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use our own login view where the token is created.

Something like that would work:

```
class MyLoginView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if <check if request header for mobile exist>:
            token = AuthToken.objects.create(request.user, expires=datetime.timedelta(days=1))
        else:
            # default TTL otherwise
            token = AuthToken.objects.create(request.user)

        user_logged_in.send(sender=request.user.__class__, request=request, user=request.user)
        UserSerializer = knox_settings.USER_SERIALIZER
        context = {'request': self.request, 'format': self.format_kwarg, 'view': self}
        return Response({
            'user': UserSerializer(request.user, context=context).data,
            'token': token,
        })
```

And finaly point to this view for the login url instead of original django-rest-knox login view

Comment: I sorted out this long ago...but anyhow thank you very much